# Redirect to a page in same directory - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, redirect

I want to redirect to a page in the same directory.

```
function redirect() {
    window.location.href = "Addform.php";
}
```

It go inside the function but `window.location.href = "Addform.php"` do not work.

Comment: You'll likely need to provide the whole URL, not just the end part.

Comment: I'm running in on the localhost. So, do I need to write like `localhost/Assignment 3/Addform.php`

Comment: `window.location.href = \`${location.href.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')}AddForm.php\``?

Comment: `window.location.href = "./"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative url for this:

```
window.location.href = "./Addform.php";
```